# Why does jQuery.height() work on an id, but not on a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have 20 items all the same height, all the same class "some_class".
The first item of the twenty has an id of "first_item".

When I do `$('.some_class').height();` I get 0 (which is wrong). But when I do `$('#first_item').height();` it works and I get a value.

This baffles me. Why might this be? I can't really share the web page because its a private page.

EDIT: Interesting to note that .width() works just fine, and I get the same value calling it on `#first_item` or '.some_class'.

Comment: You'll have to post some html to get some help.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/6bZZE/ I assume you have another element with that class preceding the one with the ID, and this element has height 0.

Comment: Yeah, see that example works fine... and it should work fine in my example, but it just doesn't. You're example is exactly like my situation, except I have 80+ items. I've done this many many times in other project, and all of a sudden it just doesn't work.

Comment: `.height()` will return the height of the first element in the set of matched elements. Are you sure when selecting by class that the **first element is the correct one** ?

Comment: I just triple checked. The very first element has a detected height of 178px in the element inspector. Calling height using the id selector works fine, but calling height using the class selector returns 0.

Comment: Aaaaah, I figured it out. The first one is display none. I didn't think that affected the height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you'll probably find that the class selector is returning more than one element. In this case, `height()` returns the value of the first element (this is consistent throughout the jQuery get methods); which is probably not the one you want.

If you want the height of each of the element, you should iterate over them with each;

```
$('.some_class').each(function () {
    var myHeight = $(this).height();
});
```

[jQuery height docs;](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: There is probably another element with that class which precedes the one with the ID and that element has height 0.

Comment: That is true. But all the elements in my case are the same height, so I should get a non-zero value back, but that isn't happening. I triple checked and the very first item has a height of 178. I'm not getting this value back.

Comment: I triple checked and tried it over and over. It seems like an optical illusion of code.

Comment: @trusktr: Try inspecting `$('.some_class').first()` to see which element is being matched (and which jQuery reckons has the `height()` of zero. (it it's got an ID try `alert($('.some_class').first.attr('id'));`, or `text()` to get it's contents etc.

Answer (score 1):

`$('.some_class:eq(0)').height();` should give you the proper output.

It's a basic html/css stuff, you need to understand.

'class' defines specific type of elements. Description of the class will be defined with style associated with that class. So, class is used to provide style to multiple elements of same type. For example, 20 items mentioned by you have same class. (They can not have same id).

'id' is an unique identification of an HTML element. There can not be multiple elements having same 'id'. So, 'id' is used to provide style to one uniqe element. 
Ways of writing style for class 'myClass' and id 'myId' are as below.

Comment: This should not matter since `eq(0)` is done internally as well when doing `.height()` (although in a different fashion, but it comes down to the first element in the set).

Comment: Again, because it's so fun: If a jQuery method does not return a scalar value, it always returns a jQuery object. From the `height` docs: *"Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements.*"